# Flattening in multiple rows in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

```
list[Union[dict[str, Union[dict[str, str], str]], dict[str, Union[dict[str, str], str]], dict[str, Union[dict[str, int], str]], 
dict[str, Union[dict[str, int], str]], dict[str, Union[dict[str, int], str]], dict[str, Union[dict[str, str], str]], 
dict[str, Union[dict[str, int], str]]]]
```

What will be the best way to flatten a nested dictionary in python - this is the JSON file column value I have?

I tried using recursive loop function, json_normalize function but all of them convert it in single row with multiple columns. Ideally, this should become multiple rows corresponding to each dict value.

Comment: Can you provide a real (reproducible) example of your input and the expected output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can't fully understand what you're trying to do here. It would be better if you included a sample of test input and desired output, as well as some of the code for those attempts you mentioned (*"recursive loop function, json_normalize function"*), and maybe elaborate a bit more on why you don't like the outcome... anyway, I can see why indiscriminate recursion would flatten everything, but can't you loop through the rows and flatten each row individually?